# json response showing SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 23 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: php, angularjs

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
header('Content-Type: applicatio`enter code here`n/json');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
?>

<script>
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("file.php").then(function (response) {
var d = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(d);
$scope.answers = response.data.records;
});
});
</script>
```

Response :- ["1","santosh","1","9"]["2","chandan","2","9"]
but in angularjs showing error SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: you don't need to make your query twice , `mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);` remove the first query;

Answer (score 0):

you need to collect your database results in one array, then encode it into json

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

and in your context , you may not need to directly use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) which it's **returns**:

> Returns an array of associative or numeric arrays holding result rows.

as follows:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: :-  this is array response    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => santosh
            [rollno] => 1
            [class] => 9
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => chandan
            [rollno] => 2
            [class] => 9
        )

)
and this is json response [{"id":"1","name":"santosh","rollno":"1","class":"9"},{"id":"2","name":"chandan","rollno":"2","class":"9"}] but showing SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: sorry , it was a typo in my second code sample, check it out;

Comment: you are using the first style or the second ? while loop or fetch all ?

Comment: :- $data = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
  $data[] = $row;
 }
 print_r($data);
 echo json_encode($data);

Comment: use , mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_object, and don't print_r your `$data` variable, it must working fine then;

Comment: :- Now response is [{"id":"1","name":"santosh","rollno":"1","class":"9"},{"id":"2","name":"chandan","rollno":"2","class":"9"}] but in angularJS showing this error  SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: make sure that your angular is not caching your response, your json now is valid json , test it on jsonlint.com